# C# Dynamic Button Event Handler Mechanism

Tags: c#, event-handling, xamarin.android

I am creating buttons dynamically for a user-based app. Now I have to tell the new form what text to apply to the buttons via parameters to the form, the form then creates the buttons. Now I have an issue - the events for these buttons: What is the best mechanism to get the button click events through. I cannot access the form from the originating form, and I can only pass simple data types (and arrays).

My first thought is to use a code to reffer to the appropriate method in a static class - basically, pass an array of ints through with the names of the buttons and their onclick handler calls one method - handle(int code) -> where code is used in a giant switch statement to call the appropriate method.

But I doubt this is the best mechanism. I would prefer to create a listener of some sort that simply listens for button clicks, and should the click be unhandled, determine which button was clicked and manage it from there.

I have looked at the observer pattern and I am not entirely convinced this is the best one to follow. The problem is not that there is no solution, the problem is that I want the BEST solution.

This is in C# for monodroid - but the impact of this information should be minimal.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you access the form from the originating form?

Comment: Because of the way that creating Android forms works - it is not some object you simply create - it is an activity instance that must be started. There is no 'activity object' to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have two options:

1. Use reflection - pass a method name to the button and that button can then invoke a method based on the string value passed. Then simply create a static class where all button methods are kept.
2. Use a switch statement - since I can have delegates that take parameters (one of them being a SENDER object) I can easily send the sender object to a method containing a switch statement which performs an action based on that object.

In my research I have determined that the former (reflection) is preferred, espcially since the number of buttons is rather large.

REFS:
http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/04/efficient-c-tip-12-be-wary-of-switch-statements/
[Large Switch statements: Bad OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505454/large-switch-statements-bad-oop)
[Method Factory - case vs. reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234421/method-factory-case-vs-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to fully understand what's actually your problem, but here's how you should deal with dynamic controls and event handlers:

```
Button myNewButton = new Button { Text = "MyCaption" };
myNewButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ((Button)sender).Text = "New text here!";
        // Another logic could be put here
    };
```

Comment: I can do this, but what I am doing is dynamic form generation. I am using an activity to inflate several versions of the same button (due to styling resctrictions) now the issue is that I have 3 or 4 activities which are loaded from the same code (re-usability). So the code is one class but made into many activities - each one with different buttons (all inflated dynamically). So now how do I create a management system for these buttons?

Answer (score 1):

If it was WPF i'd use Commanding but i don't know if it's available for monofroid. 
You may look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EventBroker.aspx