# How to use Reflection instead of switch case - C#

Tags: c#, reflection, switch-statement

I have edited my previous question because of lack of information.

I have written a class named *ReaderFactory* where I create a Method *GetAReader(string filename)*.This method returns a reader using its file-name extension. I used switch-case to select the specific reader.But my instructor suggested me to use reflection instead of switch-case.I have started to learn reflection and got stuck on its behavior. How can I implement reflection instead of switch-case in my code? GetAReader method is given below :

```
 
        public static IReader GetAReader(string _fileName)
        {
            fileName = _fileName;
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```

switch (fileExtension) 
        {
            case ".txt":
                     TextFileReader _textReader = new TextFileReader(fileName);
                         _textReader.ReadData();
                      return _textReader;

            case ".pdf":
                         PDFReader _pdfReader = new PDFReader(fileName);
                         _pdfReader.ReadData();
                         return _pdfReader;
            case ".doc":
                        //reader initialize
            case ".rtf":
                         //reader initialize
            case ".docx":
                        //reader initialize
            case ".jpg":
                        //reader initialize


        }

        return null;
    }

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859902/in-3-minutes-what-is-reflection

Comment: "Please repeat to me a largee part of the documentation. I am too lazy to read the documentation, but I promise I will not be too lazy to read it if you copy/paste it".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended

Comment: I urge you not to read about reflection as a beginner, its "powers" may encourage you to use it for areas where you should apply core concepts of the language

Comment: I see "beginner" and "reflection" six words apart. That does not bode well...

Answer (score 4):

Reflection is something very complicated, but can be used for a wide variety of things.
Some examples:

- Reading properties by the specifying the name.
- Load an assembly and get all the types of it.
- Read attributes

To make it very short, with reflection you have the power to decompile any .NET code to C# / VB or any other IL language.

I suggest you have a look at telerik's decompiler (that's a tool that let you view source code of dll's). Than you have an idea what reflection is.

Alo, here's some documentation to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx

Comment: I edited my question. can you please elaborate those question.

Comment: Don't understand me wrong, but there are already a lot of articles on Reflection. Can you explain me why you need it? I ask this because reflection is quite expensive and if there's a built in .NET solution, that might be much quicker. I will give you the explanations you need, but I just want to avoid that u use code which requires unneeded resources.

Comment: I have written a class named Reader.I used switch-case for selecting
the file extension.As there are lots of file type my instructor suggested me to use reflection instead of switch-case.I started reading about reflection and got stuck on dynamically load assembly files.So can you please explain me How can I use reflection instead of switch-case?

Comment: Ok, please edit your original question where you show your code and what the code is supposed to do. That way you will get better answers on your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I am editing my original question

Comment: Thanks. I will try to answer later today.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what your prof is saying. Can you tell me where he would use reflection and I  what context? Since reflection is very wide it's important that we know the context. Reading attributes, get types, ... Anyway. I will post some examples still today about reflection to get you started.

Comment: My instructor told me to use reflection instead of switch-case portion.

Comment: I don't see how. I'm sorry.

Comment: But I've looked around on the net and come accross to this post on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234421/method-factory-case-vs-reflection It's a discussion to see what's faster a switch or reflection. A switch will always be faster, but maybe it's a good idea to read that post. And don't hesitate to come back if you have any further questions.